# NZ Property for sale API

Tags: python, rest, gis

I failed to get approval for my application that I started to write against the TradeMe API.  My API access was not approved.  I'm therefore looking for alternatives.

Any NZ property for sale APIs out there?  I have seen realestate.co.nz which according to the github repo, might provide something in PHP and Ruby, but the Ruby repo hasn't been touched in several years.  Google API perhaps?

I'm specifically interested in obtaining geo-location information for the properties on sale.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox should let you access trademe without the need to access the main server.

Comment: True and that is how I have done basic testing but now I need representative geo-location data in order to test further.  Also,  they do say to seek approval as early as possible so as to not spend significant time developing as the app only becomes useful once running against production data.  I only need read-only access as if I am a web browser, but need structured results.

Answer (score 0):

realestate.co.nz seems to have both Javascript and Ruby APIs.  I'm going to investigate the possibility of building a Python port as their code is on github/realestate.co.nz

I have no financial interest in either TradeMe or realestate.co.nz, for the record.  Just a guy trying to avoid screen scraping.